# Update AWS Athena workgroup using CloudFormation template

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-athena

I have 2 templates those I have taken from the [AWS::Athena::WorkGroup - AWS CloudFormation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-resource-athena-workgroup.html) documentation.

The first template `athena_create.yaml` works as expected. The second template needs to modify the workgroup created in the first template. But I get an error:

> MyCustomWorkGroup already exists in stack
>   arn:aws:cloudformation:us-east-1:XXX:stack/a1/7cc670a0-8d19-11ea-872c-12217e59f19f

Here is the code. create template works correctly.

athena_create.yaml

```
Resources:
  MyAthenaWorkGroup:
    Type: AWS::Athena::WorkGroup
    Properties:
      Name: MyCustomWorkGroup
      Description: My WorkGroup
      State: ENABLED
      Tags:
        - Key: "key1"
          Value: "value1"
        - Key: "key2"
          Value: "value2"
      WorkGroupConfiguration:
        BytesScannedCutoffPerQuery: 200000000
        EnforceWorkGroupConfiguration: false
        PublishCloudWatchMetricsEnabled: false
        RequesterPaysEnabled: true
        ResultConfiguration:
          OutputLocation: s3://path/to/my/bucket/
```

athena_update.yaml

```
Resources:
  MyAthenaWorkGroup:
    Type: AWS::Athena::WorkGroup
    Properties:
      Name: MyCustomWorkGroup
      Description: My WorkGroup Updated
      State: DISABLED
      Tags:
        - Key: "key1"
          Value: "value1"
        - Key: "key2"
          Value: "value2"
      WorkGroupConfigurationUpdates:
        BytesScannedCutoffPerQuery: 10000000
        EnforceWorkGroupConfiguration: true
        PublishCloudWatchMetricsEnabled: true
        RequesterPaysEnabled: false
        ResultConfigurationUpdates:
          EncryptionConfiguration:
            EncryptionOption: SSE_S3
          OutputLocation: s3://path/to/my/bucket/updated/
```

The update template mentioned above does not work as expected.

Comment: I guess you are deploying them as two separate templates? In that case you can't do this because the two templates create two WorkGroups of same Name: `MyCustomWorkGroup` .

Comment: How do I update a workgroup using cloudformation template?

Comment: You create the stack using first template. Then once done, you go to the stack and click update. This will updated the orginal stack, instead of creating new one.

Comment: Thanks. Got it. Is there any way to update default workgroup using cloudformation?

Comment: If you don't mind I will make an answer for future reference. Unfortunate not that familiar with Athena. Just new why CloudFormation was giving your problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for the error is that the two templates were used to create two independent stacks. This didn't work because they two Athena WorkGroups of same Name: `MyCustomWorkGroup`.

The correct way to perform create and update the  `MyCustomWorkGroup` is as follows:

1. Create a stack using `athena_create.yaml` file.
2. Once the stack is created, use its `Update` option to upload `athena_update.yaml` which is going to update the stack.

Comment: I will like to know if there is any way to update default template using cloudformation.

Comment: @shantanuo I would say no. CloudFormation can update only resources it has created. Default/primary workgroup is a resource external to cloudformation.

Comment: It's possible. Just add "DeletionPolicy: Retain" line and use "With existing resources (import resources)" option to update primary workgroup.

Comment: This can help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61200196/how-to-update-athena-output-location-using-cloudformation/62165742#62165742